# Webpack alias with <img> src and file-loader not copying image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, resolve, webpack-file-loader

I have an issue where file-loader isn't copying images that are using a resolve.alias in the image src.

An example:

```
<img src="assets/images/image.jpg"/>
```

The resolve.alias is:

```
alias: {
  'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/assets'),
}
```

And the file-loader is:

```
{ test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/images/[name].[ext]' }
```

This is in a React/Redux app. I know I can use require but some images use a variable, and if that variable equals a value that has no image, the full app will crash due to failure to load a module.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Webpack is a build step, so you cant use an `alias` and expect it to work with variables at runtime, sadly.

Comment: Thats a shame. I'll need to deal with horrible ../../ I think!

Answer (score 5):

You should import your image file instead of hardcoding the path of it:

```
import myImage from './assets/images/image.jpg';

...

<img src={myImage} />
```

Comment: THese images can be dynamic though, so an import wouldn't work. I have tried a require but this crashes the app if the image doesn't exist (this could happen). Using a try catch doesnt work with a variable in the require either for some reason

Comment: You can try dynamic-import: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import

Answer (score 1):

please try this one, it works for me.

```
<img src="${require(`assets/images/image.jpg`)}"/>
```